# Memory size grows exorbitantly with dynamic 2D memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, linux, memory

I have the following piece of sample code allocating 1D array:

```
#define C 3
int main() {
    int *a;
    long long N = 1000000000, i;
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N * C);
    for (i = 0; i < N * C; i++)
        a[i] = i / 2;
    printf("%d\n", a[N*C - 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code takes exactly 12 GB of data in memory.
Note that `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(int*) == 8`.

Now, if I implement a dynamic 2D array using the following code:

```
#define C 3
int main() {
    int **a;
    long long N = 1000000000, i;
    a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * C);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
           a[i][j] = i;
    printf("%d\n", a[N-1][C-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code strangely takes around 38 GB of memory (whilst it should have taken 12GB + 8GB (for array of pointers) = 20 GB.

Strangely enough, in the second sample code, if I increase the value of `C` to 4, 5, 6, the memory consumed is exactly the same (38 GB), while for `C=7` and `C=8` the memory consumed is 54 GB, and for `C=16` the memory consumed is 86 GB. This doesn't fit any math I could figure out. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `malloc` (as most allocator) give **at least** given size.

Comment: First of all, this does not seem to be C++ code. Second of all, how do you measure used memory?

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array and it cannot even point to such an array.

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends. 2) Use `size_t` for memory allocation. There is no guarantee it has the same valid range as `long long` (actually it likely has not).

Comment: What @Jarod42 says, is one (aside) reason why many *undefined behaviour* bugs seem to work: because more memory was allocated than was requested.

Comment: 8GB for int* sounds legit, the second I assume would at least assume to N* 16Byte, assuming that all fragments are aligned to byte borders, or it even may be 64 byte --> memory word block boundaries. Now you have to take existing memory fragmentation into account. For the second way, there may be a lot of unused space inbetween the 16 or 64 byte blocks

Comment: Each dynamic allocation has a bookkeeping overhead of at least `sizeof(size_t)`, so you allocate at least 20 bytes per element, not 12. In addition, the allocator probably allocates blocks of a power-of-two size - up to some threshold - which is why the use doesn't grow linearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2D array is really an array of pointers to arrays of 3 `int`. The extra space required comes from the overhead in all the small arrays of 3 `int`: each of these uses 12 bytes plus a possible padding of 4 to 12 bytes and an estimated overhead of at least 8 bytes.  The total size could amount to 32GB+8GB = 40GB, which is 38GiB as reported by `top`.  Depending on the actual implementation of `malloc`, the overhead can range from a bit less to a lot more.  The memory returned by `malloc` is guaranteed to be suitably aligned for the maximum alignment requirement. On the intel 64 bit architecture, this means 16 bytes.  If the allocator is very conservative, each small array occupies 16 bytes, if not it may occupy 32 bytes or more.

You can allocate a real 2D array with no overhead this way:

```
#define C 3
int main(void) {
    long long N = 1000000000, i;
    int (*a)[C] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
            a[i][j] = i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a[N-1][C-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** trying to interpret your size observations:

```
C=3 to C=6 -> 38GiB
C=7, C=8 -> 54 GiB
C=16 ->  86 GiB
```

`top` displays memory sizes in GiB, units of 1024x1024x1024 bytes, about 8% less than GB.

The array of pointers uses exactly 8GB (8 billion bytes) with negligible overhead.

The table below summarizes the breakdown between the array of pointers and the individual arrays of `int` allocated with `malloc` for size `C`:

```
 C    used    actual   arrays  pointers  total    binary
---   ----    ------   ------  --------  -----    ------
 3     12       32      32GB      8GB     40GB   37.3GiB
 4     16       32      32GB      8GB     40GB   37.3GiB
 5     20       32      32GB      8GB     40GB   37,3GiB
 6     24       32      32GB      8GB     40GB   37.3GiB
 7     28       48      48GB      8GB     56GB   52.2GiB
 8     32       48      48GB      8GB     56GB   52.2GiB
16     64       80      80GB      8GB     88GB   82.0GiB
```

My interpretation is:

Small memory blocks allocated by `malloc` are rounded up to a size multiple of 16 plus 8, plus an extra 8 byte overhead for the arena bookkeeping information. The address returned by `malloc` is aligned on a 16 byte boundary, the 8 byte overhead sits just before the chunk, and the chunk size is a multiple of 16 minus 8 bytes, to allow for the next block to be aligned.

This would explain the jump from 32 to 48 bytes for C=7.

You should verify that there is a similar jump for C=11.

You could also measure the case of C=2 to see if the minimal block size is 8 or 24 bytes for a chunk size of

Comment: As I wrote, I would assume the overhead results in block alignment to whatever boundaries the OS/ malloc library uses (byte boundary or machine word)

Comment: Yes, I'm running on Intel 64 bit architecture. What I still can't figure out is, if I increase the value of C to 4, 5, 6, the memory consumed is exactly the same (38 GB), while for C=7 and C=8 the memory consumed is 54 GB, and for C=16 the memory consumed is 86 GB. If I assume padding up to 16, 32 or 64 bit, it still doesn't fit the math. Also I've monitored the total memory consumed by running top command with 0.1s refresh interval, so size may not be very exact (+ or - 1GB).

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation for the memory consumption